# i have getting issue on build apk could not resolve mobilertc , commonlib

Tags: angular, android-studio, ionic-framework

what is the solution why this error getting me

i have commonlib.aar mobilertc.aar file that i import module but again my error is not solve

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.